# What is the best way to clean the outside of audio/video cables

Tags: cable, cleaning

What is the best way to clean a cable that has gotten sticky. I know the best thing to do is to not get them sticky in the first place, but after time they get dirty/sticky all by themselves.

Lets assume that there are no breaks or cuts in the outside of the cable.

**How would one best clean the outside of a cable of stickiness without damaging it more.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For delicate cables use dish washing soap and warm water with a clean rag. Do not tug or squeeze on the cable too hard and be extra gentle with anything that has twisted pair.

For not so delicate cables rubbing alcohol on a clean rag then applied should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

When I was a a corporate photo/video shooter I found the "desk and office cleaner" everyone had worked pretty well with paper towels. Now that I shoot in the third world, it is Lysol wipes when i get back to the studio. And it is terrifying how many it takes until they come out clean...

Answer (score 1):

[Goo Gone](http://www.googone.com/). Put it on a cloth, rub it on the sticky part of the cable. Let it sit for a minute, then rub off with a dry cloth. Repeat if necessary. For this or any of the other suggested procedures, it would be a good idea to test on a small non-critical part of the cable. I've never had a problem with it though.

Comment: can you elaberate? how do you apply the product

Comment: Put it on a cloth, rub it on the sticky part of the cable. Let it sit for a minute, then rub off with a dry cloth.  Repeat if necessary. For this or any of the other suggested procedures, it would be a good idea to test on a small part of a non-critical cable. I've never had a problem with it though.

Comment: The information from your comment is great, so I edited it into the answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

goo-gone or butane lighter fluid will remove just about any gunk that has built up on your cables.

Comment: How is this different from @gauss256's answer?